# Refresh "Last modification date"

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm working with Windows-10, on an application, who is writing a lot of logfiles (99 to be exact).

I've just done something, which took around one minute, so in order to see what happened I had a look at the logfiles, whose "Last modification date" indicates they have been changed the last minute (as there are so many logfiles, I hoped finding the one logfile who contained the interesting information).

This was not working, because some logfiles are not actually closed by the application, and it seems that, when a file is not released by an application, then the "Last modification date" is not modified, as you can see in attached screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This behaviour seems to be explained in MSDN blog "[URL](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2010/12/14/file-date-modified-property-are-not-updating-while-modifying-a-file-without-closing-it/)".

Does anybody have a workaround for this? (Is there another column in Windows Explorer I can use?)

Thanks in advance